# Facebook Cache takes to long to grab my dynamic content

Tags: facebook, dynamic, facebook-like

Every time someone likes my current weather conditions of an area, it posts those conditions to their wall using the OGP XFBML with SDK. However a day or two later someone will like the same page and it will post the old weather conditions to their wall. As if its posting from Facebook's Cache of the info.

I am using og:type article and putting the weather conditions in the og:description. The only thing that changes on these pages is the weather conditions.

The goal is to post the current conditions to the user's wall every time they "Like" them.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if this is something that happens once in a whilr you can use facebook debugger for refreshing facebook's cache on your page.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
 
anyway you can add a random phrase to your link every time you change the weather and change the like plugin href attribute according to the current weather.

for example, if your site was:
http://my.domain.com/weather/ny/

make it:
 http://my.domain.com/weather/ny/RANDOM_NUMBER/

you can use htaccess on apache or rewrite url on iis in order to match the random link to uour real page

Comment: yes, you can use `RewriteEngine On` with `RewriteRule` to do that, and yes I did it many times

Answer (score 0):

You could post a GD generated image instead. Facebook updates images in feeds from time to time, unlike regular status's. Think about it, you could show an Icon for the weather conditions, and it would link to a zipcode or such.